# World Baseball Classic Citizenship rules

Tags: baseball, world-baseball-classic

Why does the [world baseball classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Baseball_Classic) have such lax [citizenship rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Baseball_Classic#Eligibility_and_participation) as compared to other international competitions, by allowing anyone who is eligible for citizenship in a country compete for that country?

Answer (score -1):

My *guess* is that many countries would have difficulty building a competitive roster and it helps balance the rosters.

For example, many of the players on the Dominican team were born in the United States and are solely citizens of the United States, but have a parent from the Dominican Republic.  If the World Baseball classic had more strict rules they'd either be on the United States team or wouldn't play at all.

Comment: Needs links to back up what you're saying, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also, Puerto Rican players are USA citizens by definition...